# Webpack prod config vs dev config issues

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, web-applications, webpack-2

I am trying to reuse one webapp that's been open sourced a while ago that was written using some Django and ReactJS... Now I am a devops engineer so my skillset when it comes to JS and even Django are fairly limited so I am stuck .. My main problem is that this webapp can run just fine locally.. so I can start it and connect using http://localhost:8000 , but whenever I try and set it up on a server and make it "public" for the internal network it fails with accessing all the JS assets.

I know the problem comes with my webpack configs but I can't sort it out.. Been trying all day but I can't even find the proper documentation since it's using Webpack 2.5.

https://github.com/tsprasath/estate/tree/master/webpack

I am attaching the link to the webpack configs from the repo.. If anyone can at least point me to the right thing to look at, that would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I would do as a first step to debugging this problem is just make the upgrade to webpack 4: it's not too big of a change, and you might be able to find more help debugging this problem. I'd upgrade to the latest webpack 3.x first, then 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its an issue with your webpack. You are trying to run your react app (which is at client side) from django server. I believe you will need to use some kind of middleware to let django know that it needs to use static files generated for react using webpack. I dont know exactly how its done, but same procedure is followed if react app needs to be served from node/express server.

Or see if this helps: https://github.com/nicholaskajoh/React-Django